# GuzzleHttp Clinet show warning errors after upgrading server

Tags: php, php-7.2, guzzle

After upgrade our machine form Debian 8 to 9 with same LEMP provisioning
this code:

```
$client = new Client(
    [
       'Connection' => 'close',
       CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true,
       CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
    ]
 );
 $client->get($fileUrl, ['save_to' => $local_xml]);
```

reproduce warning errors:

> Warning Error: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE -
> assumed 'CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE' (this will throw an Error in a future
> version of PHP)
>
> Warning Error: Use of undefined constant
> CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT - assumed 'CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT' (this will
> throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

I can define this constants in bootstrap file, but we have other php classes where we use also GuzzleHttp client with other options.

It's there other options to add this constant to client options?

Comment: have you installed curl extension into php ? can you see "curl " when you execute `php -m` on cli ?

Comment: @Arno thats good point, i don't see curl and some other extensions. Now run install script again with success.  Thanks